# VS 2010 C++ : how do I delete project target "Template"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Here I mean "Template" is a build-target name of a project, NOT a C++ template <> construct.

I just converted our master solution from VS 2008 -> VS 2010, and now I have a bunch of spurious build-targets named "Template" (alongside "Debug" and "Release).

When I check the configuration manager, none of them are referenced - i.e. there are no solution targets which specify that a project use its "template" build target.

Yet, VS 2010 refuses to let me remove it from a project nor to rename it:

```
Parameter "condition" cannot be null.
Parameter name: condition.
```

I have no idea what this means, any ideas?  (not all projects have this new, spurious target, and I cannot see a pattern to which ones do or do not).

Comment: Is the Template target defined  in the solution, the project file or both? On occasion I have had to manually edit the solution/project files to clean some things up that visual studio would not allow me to delete.

Comment: Thanks - make that an answer and I'll give it to you.  I was able to manually cut out the offending targets from the .vcxproj files.

Answer (score 2):

The solution seems to be to remove some offending XML text in the project file that gets left over from the VS2008->VS2010 conversion.

In summary, look for the tags below in your project file.  Remove them and reopen your project in Visual Studio.  You should now be able to remove the Template build target.

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <UserProperties RESOURCE_FILE="Dot.rc" />
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

Explained in detail here:
http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/07/invalid-pointer-error-in-visual-studio.html